# I have this error Synchronous XMLHttpRequest ajax

Tags: ajax, runtime-error

```
    {   jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    var scegli = '<option value="0">Scegli...</option>';
    var attendere = '<option value="0">Attendere...</option>';

    jQuery("select#province").html(scegli);
    jQuery("select#province").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    jQuery("select#comuni").html(scegli);
    jQuery("select#comuni").attr("disabled", "disabled");


    jQuery("select#regioni").change(function(){
        var regione = jQuery("select#regioni option:selected").attr('value');
        jQuery("select#province").html(attendere);
        jQuery("select#province").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        jQuery("select#comuni").html(scegli);
        jQuery("select#comuni").attr("disabled", "disabled");

        jQuery.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"select.php", 
            dataType: 'text',
            data: {id_reg:regione}, 
            success: function(data){
            jQuery("select#province").removeAttr("disabled"); 
            jQuery("select#province").html(data);       
        },
        async:false
        });
    }); 

    jQuery("select#province").change(function(){
        jQuery("select#comuni").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        jQuery("select#comuni").html(attendere);
        var provincia = jQuery("select#province option:selected").attr('value');

            jQuery.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"select.php", 
            dataType: 'text',
            data:  {id_pro:provincia}, 
            success: function(data){
            jQuery("select#comuni").removeAttr("disabled");
            jQuery("select#comuni").html(data);     
        },
        async:false
        });

    }); 
});}
```

the error is this:

> [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

where is the error? thanks

Answer (score 2):

The error is referring to these two lines

async:false

Once you have async false, this Xmlhttprequest becomes synchrous, which means the thread will wait for the ajx request to complete before continuing.

This has been considering bad practice  and gradually deprecated by Chrome and others.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried to set async: true, but the problem persists, where am I wrong?

Comment: hi , jQuery.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"select.php", 
    dataType: 'text',
    data:  {id_pro:provincia}, 
    success: function(data){
    jQuery("select#comuni").removeAttr("disabled");
    jQuery("select#comuni").html(data);  
   },
   async:true
   });

Comment: @GianfrancoCalabrese both Ajax changed to async true? You have two ajax method

Comment: Yes, in both, it is possible that the problem is localhost?

Comment: [link] (http://test.murimani.it/pillole/index.php?option=com_pillole&task=1)
de fields is COM_PILLOLE_REG_USER_REGIONE

Comment: @GianfrancoCalabrese i debuged your code and you still have async false somewhere. the ajax is a GET request on this url http://test.murimani.it/pillole/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js?9449fb794f9b39e8623b81ef0d2551e6

Answer (score 0):

You have to use global async functions in your code and call ajax method like this:

```
async function fun() {
    ...
    await $.ajax({
        ...
```

It worked for me.